# Adding timeAxis with Dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have the following dimple.js code:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart_montreal", 590, 400);
d3.csv("data/data_montreal.csv", function (data) {
data = dimple.filterData(data, "parameter", ["DCE_1_2","DCE_1_3","DCE_1_4"])
     var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
     myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
     var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "date","%m-%d-%Y-%H%M%S","%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S");//  09-11-2007 15:15 "%m/%d/%y_%X","%m/%d/%y %X"
     console.log(x);
     //x.addOrderRule("date");
     myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "values");
     myChart.addSeries("parameter", dimple.plot.area);
     myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 500, 20, "right");
     //myChart.setMargins("0%","0%","0%","30%");
     myChart.draw();
});
```

The console.log(x) returns an object; in the inspector in Chrome, I can read the values of x as:

> _max: Mon Sep 24 2007 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
> **proto**: Invalid Date
>
> _min: Tue Sep 11 2007 15:15:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
> **proto**: Invalid Date

Sample of csv:

> parameter,date,values,sample,
>
> benzene,09-11-2007-151500,150,PO1-1-110907,
>
> chlorobenzene,09-11-2007-151500,1900,PO1-1-110907,
>
> DCE_1_2,09-11-2007-151500,5500,PO1-1-110907,
>
> DCE_1_3,09-11-2007-151500,1000,PO1-1-110907,
>
> DCE_1_4,09-11-2007-151500,3000,PO1-1-110907,
>
> ethylbenzene,09-11-2007-151500,100,PO1-1-110907,

Consequently, the date shows up correctly, the the time is completely erased.

I assume it's a bug, as there's no errors being reported.

The working file is here: http://lorefolk.com/ii/iveysoldemo/demo.html#/5

Does anyone see if there's something wrong with the formatting or know a trick in d3 to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug, the time axis in dimple displays regular intervals rather than the points at which there are data.  The interval here is daily, which means midnight every day is labelled.  You can change the interval using a combination of `axis.timePeriod` and `axis.timeInterval`.  So if you wanted to draw a label every 4 hours the x axis it would look like:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart_montreal", 590, 400);
d3.csv("data/data_montreal.csv", function (data) {
    data = dimple.filterData(data, "parameter", ["DCE_1_2","DCE_1_3","DCE_1_4"])
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
    var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "date","%m-%d-%Y-%H%M%S","%m-%d-%y-%H%M%S");
    x.timePeriod = d3.time.hours;
    x.timeInterval = 4;
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "values");
    myChart.addSeries("parameter", dimple.plot.area);
    myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 500, 20, "right");
    myChart.draw();
});
```

You can see the actual values for the points in the tooltip which in your case requires a click on the relevant data point.  You'll also notice from the drop line that they don't necessarily line up with the axis point.  N.B Use `series.lineMarkers = true` if you want to make the data points easier to find.

If you want an x value per data point you need to use a category axis instead of time, but that will evenly space the points regardless of the time between them so is probably not suitable for your data.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I was just confused between categories and series.